# Wrong record displayed when create form closes

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

Inside AX2012 R3, when creating a new Return Order from the Return Order list view page (using the button in the Header), the SalesCreateOrder form opens and functions as expected.

Upon close of this form, however, instead of opening the newly created Order, instead the order that was selected in the grid is opening.

Several developers have made customization to this form, but none that (at first glance) appear relevant to this behavior.

Where would I find the behavior to open a form upon close of the SalesCreateOrder dialog?

Comment: Consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* open the created order by changing the `SalesCreateOrder.close` method:

```
public void close()
{
    Args args = new Args(this); //Change here

    // Save user's customer search type
    MCRCustSearch::saveCustSearchType(mcrCustSearchType.selection());    
    if (salesTableType)
    {
        salesTableType.formMethodClose();
    }    

    //Change here -->
    args.record(salesTable);
    new MenuFunction(menuitemDisplayStr(SalesTable),MenuItemType::Display).run(args);
    //End of change <--    

    super();
}
```

You may have to change the called menuitem if called from Return order.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of how returns are created is wrong. A form isn't opened upon closing, it's opened upon creation.

When you do `Ctrl+n` or click to create a new return order, the `ReturnTable` form actually instantiates the `SalesCreateOrder` form eventually.

To see this, place a breakpoint in the `init` method of the `ReturnTable` at `\Forms\ReturnTable\Methods\init` and then try and create a new return order.